# How to make the datatable react to filters?

Tags: javascript, vuejs3, primevue

I have applied a filter on a column of the datatable and everything(selecting filters, clear filters) works just fine, but when i click apply, the data in the table does not change based on the filter

I have honestly tried everything but nothing works

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. Please read how to ask questions: please add some code examples of what you tried https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: If you tried everything + nothing works + you don't provide any context/[repro], we just cannot help you. Try reading your question out loud to realize how powerless we are in such situation.